# use adist to determine which element only needs deletions

Tags: r, fuzzy-comparison

I've got this `vector` of `strings` (y) and a single `string` (x) which I want to compare and see which y fits x best if only deletions are considered.

```
x = "PCOR1"
y = c("PCor", "TCor", "TMMON", "INTMAX")
```

What I tried so far is to use `adist` but it leads to strange results:

```
adist(x,y,costs=c(substitutions = 0, insertions = 0, deletions = 1), ignore.case=TRUE)
```

> ```
>       [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4]
> [1,]    1    1    0    0
> ```

I can have a closer look at this doing:

```
 drop(attr(adist(x,y,costs=c(substitutions = 0, insertions = 0, deletions = 1), ignore.case=TRUE, counts=TRUE),"counts"))
```

> ```
>      ins del sub
> [1,]   0   1   0
> [2,]   0   1   1
> [3,]   0   0   5
> [4,]   1   0   5
> ```

This now tells me, if I get it right, that I need one deletion to get from "PCOR1" to "PCor", one deletion and one substitution to get from "TCOR1" to "TCor" and so on.

Why does `adist` return this if I set insertions and substitutions to 0? Is there a way to only use deletions?

I would expect something like:

> ```
>      [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4]
> [1,]   1    0    0    0
> ```

Answer (score 1):

It seems you want to return it if it is a subset of the original string. In this case `grepl()` should suffice, i.e.

```
sapply(y, grepl, x, ignore.case = TRUE)
# pcor   tcor  tmmon intmax 
# TRUE  FALSE  FALSE  FALSE
```

or

```
sapply(y, grepl, x, ignore.case = TRUE) * 1
#PCor   TCor  TMMON INTMAX 
# 1      0      0      0
```

Comment: Not exactly. I need to determin if `y` contains any of `x`, ignoring the case and allow for maximum two deletions but no substitutions or insertions. This is because `x` might be another `string`, for example it might be "M" which, of course is a subset of all strings in `y`
Thanks for the reply anyway